# When the product quantity is below the stock level it must alert that the remaining stock is luck of stack and needed to restock

Tags: php, html

****The problem is even the quantity of the the product is not below 10 the alert is still working i tried different ways but it still doesn't work any suggestion thanks in advance.****

```
<?php
$qty='prod_qty';
  if($qty <= 10){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Low stock restock it 
immedietly');</script>";
} 
?>
```

[This is the photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnOE5.png)

Comment: `'string' <= 10`? What result you expect when you compare string and number?

Comment: the string is where the number of the stock on hand please see the picture thanks

Comment: @IvanLim: no, string is always just a string, converted to `0` when you compare it against number. Use variable (from screenshot can't say what's the variable name) instead.

Comment: how sir panther sorry newbie here

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put the number (quantity) into brackets? It's an **integer**. That's no the problem however.

I've tested, and set `$qty = 4`. The echo only was shown, when `$qty <= 10`. **No problem there.**

Perhaps you get the wrong value loaded into your `$qty`?

Comment: Yes i think the problem is that my if statement does not get the value of the product quantity that shows in the picture i want to assign that everything that will below 10 in the inventory will alert the admin that one of the product is needed to restock

Comment: i need to get the value of the prod quantity how can i do it and assign it to a string?

Comment: Quantity is a sign of not a string (text) but an integer (number). Where do you get the information of the quantity? From a DB I guess?

Comment: Well, how do you read that information in? How do you process it. Normally you get a '$row' array as return value from the database where you got the information from. So the value would be the $row["prod_qty"]. The value from the column name "prod_qty".

Comment: Your question leaves way too many things unclear. Perhaps you can add more code and explanation to your post.

Comment: so christian how can i add it to my if statement? sorry for newbie skill

Comment: You should really read into PHP DataBase connections and return value handling. [link]http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: can't find the if statement sir

Comment: The problem is not in the if statement, but in the value of `$qty`.

Comment: did you know how to get the value of the $qty and put it in the if statement christian?

Comment: Sure I know that. But don't be mean. I'm not giving personal teaching and lessions^^ Just read yourself into it.